# Smallest value of n to form 900 n-digit numbers using given digits

Tags: permutations, combinations

> An $n$-digit number is a positive number with exactly n digits. $900$ $n$-digit numbers are to be formed using only $2$, $5$ and $7$. What is the minimum value of $n$ for which this is possible?

Since each place can have $3$ values, should I start by $9P3$ or $9^3$?
I started with $9P3$ and got nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider how many digits you have to choose at each spot: for the one's spot, you have $3$ digits; for the tens spot, you have three digits; all the way to the $n$th spot, you have $3$ digits to choose from.  As such, the total number of ways to make an $n$-digit number with only $2,5$ and $7$ is going to be $3^n$.

Thus we're looking for the smallest integer $n$ such that $3^n\ge 900$, or in other words, since the log function is increasing, $n\ln(3)\ge\ln(900)$ or, dividing by $\ln(3)$, $n\ge6.19$.  Thus, $n=7$